# Is there a pure CSS way to change checked radio button label's style when another label is hovered?

Tags: html, css

I'm styling labels to take place of the standard browser-defined radio button controls. I have a `:hover` style and a `:checked` style for the labels.

But it's not clear at a glance whether clicking a button will "uncheck" the currently-checked button. So I would like to change the style of the checked label when another label is hovered.

I have coded an example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e33e9bt9/)).

**Current Behavior:**

(My screenshot tool removed it, but the cursor is over Radio Button Three. Radio Button One is checked.)

[image]

**Desired Behavior:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<form type="post">
  <input type="radio" name="group" id="radio1" /> 
  <label for="radio1">Radio Button One</label>

  <input type="radio" name="group" id="radio2" /> 
  <label for="radio2">Radio Button Two</label>

  <input type="radio" name="group" id="radio3" /> 
  <label for="radio3">Radio Button Three</label>

  <input type="radio" name="group" id="radio4" /> 
  <label for="radio4">Radio Button Four</label>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: white;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

If I have to use JS, I will, but pure CSS is preferable.

Comment: what type of style do you need

Comment: I don't think it's doable in pure css, but the JS solution should be pretty easy

Comment: See if any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered) are what you're looking for

Comment: @Mohammedwahedkhan I just want to change the background color of the `:checked` label, maybe making it lighter like in the example screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the selected element is descendant or adjacent you will have difficulty doing this with CSS due to the cascading nature. However if your form has a defined bounding box, you could cheat by taking advantage of the parent's :hover state with CSS such as this:

```
form:hover input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

It is a bit of a hack, but it may give you the desired effect. I hope this helps.

Koda

Comment: Marking as correct, since this appears to be the closest I'll get without JS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Kodaloid is correct, and there's no pure CSS solution, here's a way to accomplish this effect with jQuery ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e33e9bt9/2/)).

I'll have to use this since the form I'm working on has whitespace between buttons.

**Add an additional class for the checked label to make it pink:**

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label.otherhover {
    background-color: pink;
}
```

**Use jQuery to toggle the class at the appropriate times:**

```
$("input[type='radio'] + label").hover(
    function () {
        if (!$("#" + this.htmlFor).is(":checked")) {
            $("input[type='radio']:checked + label").addClass("otherhover");
        }
    }, 
    function () {
        if (!$("#" + this.htmlFor).is(":checked")) {
            $("input[type='radio']:checked + label").removeClass("otherhover");
        }
    }
);
```